# Passing object to ng-include through ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-init, angularjs-ng-include

I need to pass a an object containg user information to a ng-include template. the template is expected to be used in more than the view I am currently wokring in, thus the issue, since I can't use the regular "ctrlName.user.name", since I can't know from which controller the object is comming. Here is the controller:

```
angular.module('QW').controller('schoolCtrl', function ($state, schoolHandler, userHandler) {

var vm = this;

vm.activeTemplate;
vm.activeTemplateUser;
vm.templates = {
    'edit-employee' : 'app/templates/edit-profile-modal.html'
}


vm.editEmployee = function(){

    // This part should naturally come from database normally
    vm.activeTemplateUser = {
        firstname : "John",
        lastname : "Doe",
        email : "John@Doe.com",
        phonenumber : "XXXX XXXX XXXX",
        profile_pic : "assets/img/profile.png"
    }

    // Fetches template URL
    vm.activeTemplate = vm.templates["edit-employee"];

    // Opens modal in which the data is to be inserted
    var inst = $('[data-remodal-id=edit-user-modal]').remodal();
    inst.open();
}
});
```

Here follow my include and init:

```
<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="edit-user-modal" data-remodal-options="hashTracking: false" id="edit-user-modal">

        <div ng-init="user = school.activeTemplateUser" ng-include="school.activeTemplate"></div>

</div>
```

And lastly my template:

```
<div id="edit-profile-information">

    <h5>Förnamn{{user.name}}</h5>

</div>
```

So in short, I want activeTemplateUser to represent user inside the template by setting:

```
  ng-init="user=school.activeTemplateUser"
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the property `name` is used in the template. But in the object `user` is not the properties of `name`.